# Bootstrap glyphicon not centred with text

Tags: c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a form and am trying to do validation on my bootstrap form, using bootstrap components. I'm using a c# class library to do my server side validation, and then use the c# code-behind to validate the styles when the form meets a validation condition. I use a panel to hold my form control as such:

```
<asp:Panel ID="TeacherNamePanel" CssClass="form-group" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbTeacherName" CssClass="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Teacher-in-charge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

and in the code-behind to validate the style:

```
if (teacherName.Length == 0)
{
      TeacherNamePanel.CssClass = "form-group has-error has-feedback";
      Label span = new Label();
      span.CssClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback";
      span.Attributes["style"] = "vertical-align:middle";
      TeacherNamePanel.Controls.Add(span);
}
else
      TeacherNamePanel.CssClass = "form-group";
```

However, my glyphicon is not centred in my form's input control, it's too low. Anyway to rectify this problem? Tried to change the positioning for "top" in the css for `.has-feedback .form-control-feedback` but to no avail.

[image: Here's how it looks:]

Comment: Could you put together a demo please? Just as a guess, try changing `span.Attributes["style"] = "vertical-align:middle";` to `span.Style.Add("vertical-align", "middle");`

Comment: @Dura did you mean an image of my problem? Added it in!

Comment: Cheers, did you try what I suggested? Does the `vertical-align` property actually get applied?

Comment: @Dura I just tried, but it didn't work! :-( The remove glyphicon is exactly where it still is as shown in the picture. The vertical-align property didn't seem to get applied.

Comment: It might be that because your `span` is an instance of `Label`, it doesn't like `style`. When you inspect the `span` element in the browser, what `css` does it have?

Comment: Hi @Dura, the css works, the vertical-align property is shown to be applied. But it's still out of place! The codes seem to be inserting the span in the next line, not on the same line as the input.

Comment: What does it happen if you try hard code the values in html and css, rather than setting them from code behind? Is it still wrong when you do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69195/discussion-between-user3763216-and-dura).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I copied the following css from bootstrap.css

```
.has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
right: 0;
display: block;
width: 34px;
height: 34px;
line-height: 34px;
text-align: center;
}
```

and pasted it in my own stylesheet and adjusted top and right to fit my input box. Thanks for your help and advice guys!

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of ways to achieve what your after.

1. Use different syntax:

`span.Attributes["style"] = "vertical-align:middle";`

to

`span.Attributes.Add("vertical-align", "middle");`

2. Add a `css` class and apply it to label with the `CssClass` property. For instance:

This goes in your css file

```
 .centerAlign {vertical-align: middle;}
```

then the following should work

```
span.CssClass = "centerAlign";
```

and will generate:

```
<span class="centerAlign">your text</span>
```

Comment: Hiya I tried hardcoding it but it doesn't work! I used the sample code from w3 schools `<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputError">Input with error and glyphicon</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
    </div>` but i realized the glyphicon is still out of place

Comment: @user3763216 Glad you got it working. Please consider upvoting answers if they were at all helpful, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try using !important to force the attribute to override predefined ones like so:

```
span{vertical-align:middle!important;}
```

Comment: The vertical-align property doesn't affect the position of the glyphicon :-(